# What is a good sensing element to monitor corrosion in a bridge structural health monitoring system?

Tags: electrical-engineering, civil-engineering, bridges, sensors

The question relating to [measuring structural integrity of bridges](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1906/can-the-structural-integrity-of-bridges-be-measured-in-real-time-for-safety) brought awareness to six categories of [structural health monitoring of bridges](http://www.oregon.gov/ODOT/HWY/BRIDGE/docs/SHM_SCL_submission.pdf). They are

1. Bridge foundations
2. Concrete superstructures
3. Movable bridges
4. Steel fatigue
5. Structural dynamics
6. Corrosion protection

[image: gusset plates]

**Question:**

What is a good sensing element to measure **bridge corrosion**? What characteristics in this sensing element make it a good candidate for corrosion monitoring? Is an [ultrasonic transducer](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/what-is-radial-and-thickness-mode-vibration-in-a-piezo-electric-ceramic-disc-tra) a good candidate?

Answer (score 4):

**Ultrasonic Thickness Gauge**

One of the most common methods of measuring steel plate thickness is an [ultrasonic thickness gauge](http://www.steelconstruction.info/Weathering_steel#Monitoring_of_steel_thickness). These gauges can be used while performing a bridge inspection to determine changes in steel plate thickness between inspections.  These are also used to confirm the actual thickness of a nominally specified plate.

This only shows corrosion changes between inspections. It doesn't continuously monitor corrosion.

**Continuous Measurements**

Continuous monitoring of steel corrosion is an interesting topic of research for strands of suspension bridges. There are a [lot of methods](http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/publications/research/infrastructure/structures/bridge/14024/index.cfm) that have been researched, these mostly rely on detecting minor changes in electrical, magnetic, or acoustic changes in the steel strands. The types studied are:

- Linear polarization resistance (LPR) sensors.
- Coupled multiple array sensors (CMASs).
- Bimetallic (BM) or galvanic sensors.
- Temperature-relative humidity sensors.
- Acoustic emission (AE).
- Magnetostrictive (MS).
- Main magnetic flux method (MMFM).

**Concrete Reinforcing**

It is also useful to measure and detect any corrosion occurring in the reinforcing steel embedded in concrete. These types of [monitors](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/04/100421111355.htm) are useful to determine corrosion so that remediation measures can be planned before more visible damage has occurred. In concrete, this damage is usually in the form of spalled concrete.